# How to run a trackingscript after page is completely done loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to keep my webpages rendering as fast as possible. I wish to wait with running my google Analytics-code until everything else is done. Could this cause any problems/caveats and what would be the best event to listen for when doing this?

```
$(document).ready
$(window).load
```

Something else?

This is the google tacking code. It renders a javascript that in turn makes a http-request via a tracking-pxiel.

```
//ga
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: The script is loaded asynchronously. It will have no impact on your page load times.

Comment: Looks good, however, i Minify my javascript now, although I suppose if it is deferd, that won't matter...

Comment: @brso05 I *would* say "no impact". It is a tiny script that is almost guaranteed to be served from cache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a Asynchronous loading?
Read about it here ->
[Tracking Basics (Asynchronous Syntax)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?csw=1)